# Why aren't I getting the full index! (python list)

Tags: python, list, indexing, range

Input:

```
def part3 (x):  
    for i in range (len(x)):  
        while i <= len(x):  
            print (x[i]) 
            return x[i+1]  


x=[5,2,3]  
x.sort()  
print(x[0],x[1], x[2])  
print(part3(x))
```

Output:

```
2 3 5  
2  
3
```

my question: Why don't I get the 5 after the 3?!?! Shouldn't the function go to x[2]?!?!

Comment: You are not incrementing your `i` in the while loop

Comment: This code reads really weirdly. Why are you looping through the values, but then using the values as indices?

Comment: Why are you looping over indices? That's not Pythonic and you are making more work for yourself by doing it. The whole thing doesn't even make sense either as you then return on the first iteration regardless.

Comment: I'm trying to print all the values in the list without knowing specific index, so I thought I had to loop over the indices...in the above example, I want to get 2/3/5

Answer (score 2):

The function is returning on the first iteration of your loop(s) because you have a `return` statement there. So when you have

```
print(part3(x))
```

First `print(x[i])` (where `i = 0` since this is the first iteration) is executed within your `while`-loop and then the return value of the function (`x[i+1]`) is printed by the original print-statement above.

After you call `x.sort()`, `x` will be `[2, 3, 4]`, so `x[0]` is `2` and `x[0+1] = x[1]` is `3`, which explains your output.

Not really sure what you wanted to achieve with this code so it's hard to give you suggestions as to how to fix it. If you just wanted to print the contents of `x` then you're making it *waayy* more complicated than it has to be, as you can simply do

```
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

---

Notice that you *do not* need a return statement here, so you don't need that superfluous `print`; i.e.

```
print(part3(x))
```

would just become

```
part3(x)
```

since you are doing the printing in the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the loop wrong.  I assume the point is to print each element of `x`.

You want:

```
def part3(x):
    for element in x:
        print(element)
```

Now note:

1. You don't need a while loop inside the for loop.
2. You don't want to return anything while in the loop since that will break out of the loop and exit the function.
3. In python, you can loop over the array directly without using an index variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can see '2' as a result of inner print, you seeing '3' as a result of print 'return x[i+1]' and you don't see '5' bcoz you left your while loop and a function.

If all that you need is to print all the values and return the last one you can try this:

```
def part3 (x):  
    for val in x:  
       print val 
    return x[-1]
```

if you need to know indexes then you can try enumerate:

```
def part3 (x):  
    for i, val in enumerate(x):  
       print i, val 
    return x[-1]
```